# Placing Maps in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft I created a huge map of my world. I want to see how I can place this map so everyone can see it without the need for individual maps.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using Dynmap? Its a browser based map that updates on a real-time bases. http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1543523-dynmap-dynamic-web-based-maps-for-minecraft/

Comment: By 'created a huge map', how do you mean? Multiple in game map items?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to place a map in the world, you must place it in an [Item Frame](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_Frame).

---

1. To craft an Item Frame, place eight sticks around a piece of leather.

   [image]
2. Hold the frame and right-click to place it against a block, empty.

   [image]
3. Then, hold the map and right-click in the frame to place it in the frame.

   [image]

---

You may wish to copy the map first, so you can walk around with the copy to keep it up to date. (You can also take the map out of the frame by left-clicking on it.)

If what you want is a larger map, covering multiple blocks (as you might have seen in images and videos of major servers), then you cannot do this using a single map; you must create *many maps, each covering adjacent sections of the terrain*, and put each one in a separate item frame.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot please?

Comment: Sure, but it'll be a few hours before I have time.

Comment: Per request by @Peter_V, I have added an image (link) of an item frame in a map. Here you go: http://minecraftsnapshots.tumblr.com/page/6 The picture will be on the page, you just have to scroll down. And to answer your question, just place the map on the item frame and you're done! Simple as that!